# sending Bitmap to WebMethod inside web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, bitmap, client

In my project I have a web service and a simple client. I need to send a Bitmap parameter from the client to my web service (ASP.NET) via WebMethod.

Client side:

```
public static void Main() {
           ServiceReference1.ServiceSoapClient ser = new ServiceReference1.ServiceSoapClient();
           Bitmap j = new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\user\\Pictures\\Saved Pictures.Facebook_icon.jpg");
           ser.img(j); 
    }
```

Web service side:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void img (Bitmap pic)
    {
        pic.Save("c:\\temp\\img2.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
```

When I try to build the client it throwing an error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'tests.ServiceReference1.Bitmap' tests   C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\tests\tests\Program.cs  18

Is someone knows how to fix it?
I tried to find how to convert it but couldn't find anything. I also tried to maybe convert it to byte[], but it wasn't so good.

Comment: Try adding a reference to the System.Drawing dll in your client-side project, and then update the service reference (or maybe even delete it and re-add)

Comment: I've already added this reference. It's not it.